# 7Zip add encryption to files

Tags: archive, 7zip

I have a .7z archive that I manage using 7zFM (File Manager) and I can easily add objects to this archive. However the objects in the archive are encrypted with AES like I want them to be, but when I add something new I cannot seem to add encryption to that file within the archive unless I decrypt the entire archive, then recrypt it.

Is there an easy way to add encryption, or perhaps remove encryption, of specific files within a .7z archive?

Answer (score 16):

1. Select new files to be added
2. Right click (context menu) -> 7-Zip -> Add to archive..
3. Select an existing archive
4. Encryption, enter password
5. Click OK

Comment: If you don't see **7-Zip** on the context menu, you may have the 32-bit version of 7-Zip installed on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Install the 64-bit version of 7-Zip to add the missing context menu item. [Source](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/85f6c556/)

Comment: If you already have the archive open in 7-Zip, make sure to close it before adding the file; otherwise, the archive will be "in use" and can't be overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

You can do either like in @Tomasz's answer or just select file you wanna archive → RMB {context menu} → *7-Zip* → *Add to archive...*:

1. *Archive format* → *7z*;
2. *Encryption* {group} → ***Encrypt file names*** {checkbox} → Activate.

After that, all files that will be added to the archive via drag-and-drop will be **automatically encrypted**.

7-Zip 19.00 (x64), 2019-02-21.